# How to calculate a proportion of joined documents?

Tags: mongodb

I have a **user** collection, say:

```
{
   "user_id" : "123",
   "name" : "Fred"
}
{
   "user_id" : "456",
   "name" : "Sally"
}
{
   "user_id" : "789",
   "name" : "Sue"
}
```

and a **content** collection:

```
{
   "_id" : "aaa",
   "title", "Gone with the wind",
}
{
   "_id" : "bbb",
   "title", "Catcher in the rye",
}
{
   "_id" : "ccc",
   "title", "Star wars",
}
```

then a **tracking** collection, that tracks which users have read which content:

```
{
   "content_id" : "aaa",
   "user_id" : "123",
   "timestamp" : ISODate(...)
}
{
   "content_id" : "aaa",
   "user_id" : "456",
   "timestamp" : ISODate(...)
}
{
   "content_id" : "bbb",
   "user_id" : "123",
   "timestamp" : ISODate(...)
}
```

I'm trying to work out how to construct a pipeline that would tell me what proportion of users has read each content item. In this example there are 3 users, so my result set would look something like:

```
{
   "title" : "Gone with the wind",
   "usage" : 0.66  
}
{
   "title" : "Catcher in the rye",
   "usage" : 0.33  
}
{
   "title" : "Star wars",
   "usage" : 0.0  
}
```

(Usage = 0.66 = (2 content reads) / (3 users))

I can group and count the usage in raw numbers, but I can't work out how (from within a pipeline) to compare those numbers as a proportion of the total number of users. In SQL I would have retrieved the total users into a var then used that, but I haven't yet found a similar approach in mongodb.

I also though that it might be possible to build the pipeline on the user table, and somehow count content joined in with a $lookup - but I'm struggling with the syntax.

Is there some obvious way that I'm missing?
Thanks

Comment: did you try using `$project` and `$divide`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, let me state some assumptions I'm making since they were not specified.

1. We want the proportion of users that have viewed a particular piece of content at least once from the number of **all** users, not the users who have viewed some content (there may be dormant users who have viewed no content).
2. Each document in the *tracking* collection represents one instance of a user viewing one content, so, there may be multiple documents with the same user_id and content_id that have different timestamps because one user may view the same content multiple times.

```
    {
        "content_id" : "aaa",
        "user_id" : "123",
        "timestamp" : ISODate(...)
    }
    {
        "content_id" : "aaa",
        "user_id" : "456",
        "timestamp" : ISODate(...)
    }
    {
        "content_id" : "bbb",
        "user_id" : "123",
        "timestamp" : ISODate(...)
    }
    {
        "content_id" : "aaa",
        "user_id" : "123",
        "timestamp" : ISODate(some other timestamp)
    }
```

Firstly, we must know the number of all users. I couldn't find a way to do this in the same aggregation pipeline as the rest of the calculation. In fact, to account for the "dormant users" mentioned in the first assumption above, we can just query the count and store it in a variable in our code, which we can pass on to the subsequent aggregation.

```
db.getCollection("users").count({})
```

Let's say we store this in `user_count`.

Then we apply the following aggregation query:

```
db.getCollection("tracking").aggregate([{
    $lookup: {
        "from": "content",
        "localField": "content_id",
        "foreignField": "_id",
        "as": "content"
    }
},
{
    $unwind: {
        path: "$content"
    }
},
{
    $group: {
        _id: "$content",
        users: {
            $addToSet: "$user_id"
        }
    }
},
{
    $project: {
        "_id": 0,
        "title": "$_id.title",
        "proportion": {
            $divide: [{
                    $size: "$users"
                },
                user_count
            ]
        }
    }
}])
```

I took some mock data and tried it on Mongoplayground, feel free to try it out (user_count is made constant at 3 since their platform does not support variables):
https://mongoplayground.net/p/HYigCrsTcaA

Thanks for reading. And if anyone has any improvements/optimizations to point out, do feel free.

Comment: Thanks Anuj, that answers my question: I need to get the user count from outside the current pipeline.

Comment: Thanks! I'd be grateful if you could mark it with a green tick if it answers your question.